# Getting blank screen in Perl CGI when it does some pre-processing and spinner is shown much later

Tags: javascript, html, perl, cgi

I have added a spinner in Perl CGI script that is shown when the page gets loaded using onload() event.  Before the page loads, it has to do some pre-processing to generate the results to be shown on the screen. For that duration a blank screen is shown and much later the spinner pops up.  How to show the spinner before the pre-processing starts so that blank screen is never shown?

The code towards spinner is:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

Database processing....

    print <<END_HTML;
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        function showSpinnerTop() {
                document.getElementById('spinner_top').style.display = 'inline';
        }
        
        function hideSpinnerTop() {
                document.getElementById('spinner_top').style.display = 'none';
        }
        </script>
    </head>  
        
    <body onLoad="showSpinnerTop();">
            <div id="spinner_top" style="display: none;">
            <img class="centered" src="spinner.gif" height="20px" width="20px">
            <p class="centered" style="top:53%">Updating...</p>
            </div>
    </body>
    </html>
END_HTML
```

Comment: You probably want the CGI script to *not* do any database processing, especially not before it outputs the HTML. Instead have it output the HTML, and the HTML to using AJAX to call a second script to do the database processing, updating the page when it's done.

Comment: To show the spinner before the preprocessing starts and avoid the blank screen, you can use asynchronous techniques such as AJAX to separate the processing logic from the rendering logic.